# Hapi reply file

Tags: hapi.js

This code doesn't work in version 9.0.3:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function() {
        file: 'templates/index.html'

    }
});
```

Error:

```
de_modules/hapi/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:723
    throw new Error(msgs.join(' ') || 'Unknown error');
          ^
Error: Unknown handler: file
```

In version 8 it worked well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've resolved the problem. From last versions this possiblity was cutted away. After I include "inert" module and registered it, that works fine.

Comment: i hadn't tested my 'solution' far enough to notice it broke elsewhere. I returned to provide this answer - happy you figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

not quite sure why at the moment, but the structure of the call has changed a bit. This worked for me.

```
  handler: function(request, reply){
    reply.file('/template/index.html');
  }
```

found it here http://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files

Answer (score 0):

If you have vision and inert in your package.json, you need to register them as a plugin.

```
 server.register([require('vision'), require('inert')], function (err) {
     if (err) console.log(err);
 });
```